# What should I use to find the convergence of the series $n\arctan\frac{1}{n^3}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, divergent-series

I thought of using comparison test and used the other series as $V_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ . Now using the limit comparsion rule and LH rule to evaluate limit $$\frac{\arctan(\frac{1}{n^3})}{\frac{1}{n^3}}$$
I get the answer as 1 so it should converge as $\frac{1}{n^3}$ converges (p series test) but the book says it is diverging. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By
$$\arctan x\leq x$$
for $x>0$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\arctan\dfrac{1}{n^3}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your method is O.K.:

By LH we get $\frac{\arctan x}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$, hence there is $c>0$ such that

$0 < \frac{\arctan x}{x} \le 2$  for $x \in (0,c)$. This gives

$ \arctan(1/n^3) \le 2/n^3$  for $n$ large.

Comment: So that means it is converging and the book is wrong about it being divergent, no? Thank you so much. Also, I used the expansion for arc tan function and it came out to be convergent that way as well.

Comment: Yes, the book is wrong.